# Mysql Two table join Query not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to integrate a two tables `order` and `orderdetails` table with an id of `ord_id`. My code is not working.

```
public function orderview()
{  
    $orderid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $data["order"]=$this->db->join('tbl__order', 'tbl__order_detail.ord_id = tbl__order.ord_id',$Query=' where ord_id='. $orderid);    
    $this->load->view('manage/orderpayment/view',$data);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you ever work with Codeigniter before?
Your **Model** function must look like this. Call this function from your **Controller** to return data, then you can process this data and send it to your **View**.

```
public function orderview(){
    $orderid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->select('tbl__order.*, tbl__order_detail.ord_id as tbl__order_id');
    $this->db->from('tbl__order');
    $this->db->join('tbl__order_detail', 'tbl__order_detail.tbl__order_id = tbl__order.ord_id');
    $this->db->where('tbl__order.ord_id', $orderid);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

**In "join" you can use as third argument left, right, outer etc.**